# I facing error on facebook sdk login using yii2

Tags: facebook, yii2, cross-site

Actually I'm trying to get user Long lived access token and user id with facebook sdk plugin in yii2. But problem I facing is that when we click on facebook login button it will go to the facebook page correctlly and login successfully, but when it came to return website url it show some error Like Cross-site state param is missing or When i remove this error than it will show me

> Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException

Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds

> exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message
>   'Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state"
>   missing from persistent data.' in
>   /home/host4lev/public_html/social_post/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php:244
>   Stack trace:
>   /home/host4lev/public_html/social_post/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php(221):
>   Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->validateCsrf()
>   /home/host4lev/public_html/social_post/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php(510):
>   Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->getAccessToken()
>   [internal function]:
>   frontend\controllers\SiteController->actionChecklogin()
>   /home/host4lev/public_html/social_post/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(55):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>   /home/host4lev/public_html/social_post/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(154):
>   yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
>   /home/host4lev/public_html/social_post/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(454):
>   yii\base\Controller->runAction('checklogin', Array)
>   /home/host4lev/public_html/social_post/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(100):
>   yii\base\Module->runAction('site/checklogin', Array)
>   /home/host4lev/public_html/social_post/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375):
>   yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
>   /home/host4lev/public_html/social_post/frontend/web/index.php(17):
>   yii\base\Application->run() {main}

I tried lot's of solution but doesn't make any effect so please give some suggesion on that.

And this same code running perfectly on `localhost` but when do it to live server it come with error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got an answer for my question.Actually problem is not in my code when i checked my cpanel configuration than i find that my **port 80** is **blocked** so it want accepting the response of facebook api when **fix(unblock port 80)** that all happen good for me. Thank you so much for your all suggetions

Answer (score 0):

This is because of cross domain csrf checking. You need to allow cross domain in your controller.  add below code in your controller.

```
 public function behaviors()
 {
   return [
    'corsFilter' => [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
     ],
   ];
 }
```

Comment: i did what you suggest in my siteCorntroller.php but no effect happen error still remain same please give me more suggestions and i also change my domain as well to resolve this error but won't be resolve it